# How do I effectively defeat the Wall of Flesh?

Tags: terraria

I've been having trouble defeating this monster. Even with lots of buff potions, health potions, high tier armor (Molten), and ranged weapons with plenty of ammo (Minishark), I can't seem to kill this boss.

Worse, when I get it down to about 2000 hp, even if I'm fairly far away, it'll suck me in and continually rise towards the skybox, which doesn't allow me to do anything for some reason.

How do I defeat the Wall of Flesh? What gear should I be using and what kind of potions do I need?

Comment: The "rising to the skybox" part sounds like a bug, the wall of flesh is not supposed to ever come up out of hell.

Comment: Is there any fix for that then? It's frustrating because I've been through at least 15 Guide Voodoo Dolls, and whenever I get him close to death, he starts moving towards the skybox, forcing me to go up there, which gets me stuck

Comment: Did the accepted answer work or do I try to find what might cause it? I never had it happen to me though... I just read somewhere (on the wiki IIRC) that there is a bug where he might rise up to the top of the map.

Comment: Accepted answer actually worked pretty well.  You were right @Arperum, it was a glitch, so I had to remove most of my original bridge and make another one out of wooden platforms.  Instead of using the Water Bolt strategy, I used a Minishark with Meteor Shots coupled with Buff Potions.

Comment: Note that he "sucks you in" when you get behind him, or you get too far ahead of him.  Keep him on screen.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It sounds like you have the right idea, but here's some tips or suggestions. Buff potions definitely help, and also you will want to make sure you are using the Greater Health Potions, not the lesser ones of course.

If you haven't done so already, I suggest you try making a very long bridge. It doesn't have to be completely flat but at least enough that it's very easily traverse-able and you won't get stuck somewhere by accident or fall into lava. You'll want to focus more on the battle than trying to get around down there.

My weapon of choice for this battle would be one of the flails (Or any big Sword such as Night's Edge) for the numerous mini enemies attached to the wall. Flails take them out easily and quite efficiently since you can hit almost all of them at once. Once those are all done for, this is when switching to the minishark is a good idea. It puts out lots of damage very quickly, obviously, plus the bonus ability to save ammo every-time you shoot it. If you have the Goblin Tinkerer I suggest you put some money in reforging weapons for better stats, not necessary but makes a very noticeable impact when you get a good one.

As for your accessories, you might want rocket/specter boots to get around easier; a cobalt/obsidian shield so you aren't knocked around or into lava, and also in case there any exposed hellstone you could accidentally walk onto; and a Band of Regeneration to quickly recover lost HP. The other two are up to your preference really. I would also suggest reforging these to try and get the Warding prefix (+4 defense). Again not necessary but it will help tremendously in the long run. Especially since having 5 warding accessories means +20 defense.

You can also try to focus on magic items to defeat it. A Vilethorn also makes quick work of the smaller enemies while a space gun (with full meteor armor) will constantly damage the actual Wall without ever using mana. A Demon Scythe is definitely my favorite weapon to use against it though. It will hit everything it passes through, and while it's "charging up", the boss can be directly over it getting hit 3-5 times guaranteed. The only problem is how hard is can sometimes be to find.

If you do decide to use magic items make sure you have a full 200 Max Mana and some Mana potions as well. Restoration potions can also help here as they give back both mana and HP but will give the "Potion Sickness" debuff on use, unlike regular Mana potions. You can also get a Mana Flower to equip. This will automatically use mana potions for you so that you won't have to worry about how much mana you currently have.

Once you do manage to defeat it the first time, beating it again will just get easier since you will have access to higher tier items.

Comment: Note that you only do damage if you hit the eyes or the mouth.

Comment: honeyfin fish are even better at healing you than healing potions (120hp vs 100hp). Also, someone made a great 'Wall of Flesh kill on the First Night!' [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uwRYDoRp8TU] video where they had no armor at all but made a bunch of molitov cocktails to deal damage to it.

Answer (score 10):

You can kill the wall of flesh in under a minute with...Beenades...Ok so go off into the jungle and kill the queen bee a couple time (she is a easymode boss) Or just build a couple Abeeminations Which are quite easy to make (On the console at least) here's the link http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Abeemination. If you kill her about 4 or 5 times (It should be easy with A flame lash or molten fury), you should get 70-85 Beenades. I had molten armor when I did this but it can be done with platinum. so once you awaken The Wall Of Flesh, take out a couple of the hungry with a sword, throw those Beenades like a mad man, upon Contact they send out a swarm of bee's which do like 30 damage each, After about 45 seconds they eat the wall away!

Answer (score 6):

Without repeating what has already been said, my fool proof way is to use the Phoenix Blaster with Meteorite Shots.  It's an absolute life saver as you can take out the Wall of Flesh without any buffs at all, in as little as a 500 block runway (though give yourself some breathing space) and only lose around 5 or 6 hearts (with Molten Armour).

You can craft the phoenix blaster with a handgun (found in locked gold chests in the dungeon) and 20 Hellstone bars.  Then combine regular ammo with Meteorite bars to create Meteorite Shots.

As far as strategy goes, use a big blade (Night's Edge makes it easy) to deal with all of The Hungry first.  Then lay into the Wall's eye with the blaster - on average I expend around 250 shots though they are really easy to stock up on so I wouldn't worry about being trigger happy.

Comment: I'll just add - I'm not sure how the Phoenix Blaster compares to the Minishark as I never use it but you could also try loading it with Meteorite ammo too.  Meteorite Shots will penetrate 1 enemy and keep going potentially doubling up on on damage output (if that's how you prefer to deal with The Hungry).

Comment: The phoenix blaster is definitely better than the minishark against high-armour enemies like the bosses. It does more damage per hit, so the armour has less effect

Answer (score 4):

Here is a bunch of things I'm using.

- Sturdy Phoenix blaster
- Mystic Demon Scythe (I WAS **THAT** LUCKY)
- STAR CANNON
- Minishark
- Nimble Molten Bow with hellfire arrows, they do splash damage
- Ale + Ironskin potion - It gives you +5 defence and makes it easier to melee the hungry.
- Magic Power potion.
- Archer potion
- Mana Potions.

I built a big long straight path

1. Start off by using your bow to damage the hungry
2. Shoot at it randomly with your phoenix blaster. It should be down about 6900HP
3. Use your star cannon with about 200 stars, it should be 4000HP.
4. Use grenades now and then to get a little bit more damage.
5. Now its at 3000HP, Use demon scythe to lower it to 2000HP while dodging the lasers.
6. Repeat the cycle while using potions that heal 100HP

Answer (score 4):

If you want to defeat the Wall of Flesh easily, you really need to have:

- full molten armor
- good weapons:

  - melee:(one of these can be used) You will  need

    - muramasa
    - fiery greatsword or better
  - molten bow
  - flamarang(enchanted boomerang plus 20 hellstone bars)
  - minishhark (use silver bullets)

As for accessories you may need:

- lava charm
- rocket boots
- warding panic necklace
- any other accessories you want.

The fight itself is not too difficult, you hav to kill the hungry first with your sword and then shoot the wall of flesh in the eyes or mouth

Answer (score 1):

I am still fighting the Wall of Flesh, but I have found that the Star Cannon and the Minishark work fairly well to get him down to around 1000 Hitpoints. Then you should use either the Molten Bow or The Fiery Great Sword. And if you have it, The Night's Edge.

Comment: The star cannon is an incredibly expensive weapon to use, plus even with the star cannon you still won't be able to dole out enough DPS to kill it without moving around the Underworld, which is incredibly hazardous without armor and potion

Answer (score 1):

I defeated him pretty easily with my Star Cannon and Mini Shark.  After you defeat him, you may get a gun called a Clockwork Asasult Rifle. Try to use a Demon Scythe to kill The Hungry. As you may have noticed, while you fighting The Wall Of Flesh, The Hungry drop hearts, which helps out your health. Another thing is that he will spits out Leeches, they also drop hearts which helps out your health even further.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about all that, my friend and I beat it without all that. We used Molten Armor and lots of Meteor Shots with the Minishark and Phoenix Blaster, no need for 50 defense, just stay away from it and keep shooting.

Answer (score -1):

Build a long bridge covering both sides of the world and have a minishark with 3 stacks of ammo and shoot at the mouth or near the middle

Comment: Your bridge does not need to be that long, nor do you need that much ammo to defeat the Wall of Flesh

Comment: @PrivatePansy probably not, but no harm building a bridge across the underworld to facilitate Hellstone gathering and early into HardMode the ceiling of underworld is a good place to start digging HardMode ores. Also in a small map with many Obsidian/Hellstone towers on Expert Mode, the Wall Of Flesh might really need more time and ammo to kill.

Answer (score -1):

I had full nerco armour and star cannon with around 40 stars,fire fury thing I killed him around 1-2 mins SO easy with all I got try it easy peasy all I used happy hardmode,hope to see your death from a pixie :) :D