# Terraria: Wall of Flesh Expert Mode

Tags: terraria

I am working out how to kill the Wall of Flesh on my Expert World to go on to hard mode, but I have no idea how to go about it. I have a hole into hell, a guide voodoo doll and then a lot of graves. I have full Hellstone Armor, Night's Edge, The Bee Gun, The Bow that turns wooden arrows into hell bats and a few pretty good (to me) accessories. If requested I will list them. Anybody know I should go about this or what gear I should have. I also have Demon Scythe Water Bolt Magic Missile. The Reason I am asking this is because I understand Expert Mode Wall of Flesh is like 10 times harder than regular mode.

Comment: Have you beaten the wall of flesh on regular yet? Also, it would be useful if you list your accessories.

Comment: Do you have a large flat walkway to fight it on? That will probably help a lot.

Comment: I haven't gotten to the expert mode WoF yet but [this could potentially help](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/117746/how-do-i-effectively-defeat-the-wall-of-flesh?rq=1). It's an old answer that doesn't include new accessories or weapons though

Comment: In addition to Raven's answer, I suggest chugging a lot of potions before the fight.  +Speed, +Damage, Soup, and +Regen are amazing.

Answer (score 6):

What I would suggest is to make some beenades or get them from the Queen Bee. About 30 or so should work, maybe more to be safe. They are absolutely **BRUTAL** against the Wall of Flesh, just be sure that you can make some distance between you and the wall so you dont get killed during the WoF super fast mode when he has really low health. Just don't forget the platform.
Good Luck!

Comment: I can second this suggestion - WoF melts pretty fast against Beenades, even in expert mode. The only real problem is getting them from the Queen Bee in the first place - she's pretty tough in expert mode.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way I found was the Hellwing Bow + Hellfire Arrows and a really long bridge.

The Hellwing bow has a much faster firing speed than most bows, with the "disadvantage" being that the arrows (or bats, as case may be), shoot off at a semi-random arc making it harder to hit things.

This penalty is made irrelevant in this case because Hellfire Arrows (Well, bats), explode in an AoE making accuracy less of an issue, and because the Wall of Flesh is *really hard* ***not*** to hit.

Don't forget to equip a pair of Hermes boots and drink some potions -- the Wall of Flesh speeds up ridiculously fast sub-3000 HP on expert, and you might find yourself losing with the wall at 700 hp or less. But don't give up, just keep moving right (or left, depending) and firing exploding bats and you'll conquer the Wall in no time.